# how to insert data into a single column with several where clauses

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with Category, Name and Metric Value(This is a count value).I have 3 categories and 10 category Names.I also have query for each `MetricValue`.

How do I insert values into one single column `Metric value` when each metric value has different query.

I have 10 count statements using different tables and different conditions but I need to insert these values into one single 'Metric Value' column.

metricValue 1 has  (`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Med_process`)
Metric Value2 has (`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Hrov_contracts where flag <> N`)
MetricValue 3 has (`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM all_users where orderid = 1`)

and so on upto metric Value 10.

```
category  Name  MetricValue
cat1      Nam1  5
cat1      Nam2  35
cat1      Nam3  65
```

Comment: You need an insert or an update? does the categories and names already exist in your table (in this case it's an update) or is your table currently empty (that's an insert)?

Comment: Hi, the categories and names already exist...i have a select count statement(Metric Value) for each category-Name . I have 3 categories and 10 Names. But value column is completely empty...I created a table and inserted values for Category and Names...But for each name the Metric Value I was given a count* statement.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways I can think of are:

1. Use `UNION ALL` to join individual select statements to INSERT INTO a table.

example-

```
INSERT INTO TblFInal
SELECT Category, Name, MetricValue=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Med_process)
UNION ALL
SELECT Category, Name, MetricValue=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Hrov_contracts where flag <> N)
```

2. Another way is to create a single row and then `CROSS APPLY` to unpivot it like so.

example-

```
SELECT Cat,Name,MetricValue 
FROM
(
SELECT C1='cat1', C2='cat1', C3='cat1',
N1='Nam1',N2='Nam2', N3='Nam3',
V1=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Med_process), 
V2=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Hrov_contracts where flag <> N),
V3=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM all_users where orderid = 1)
)T
CROSS APPLY
( VALUES (C1,N1,V1),(C2,N2,V2),(C3,N3,V3))CV(Cat,Name,MetricValue)
```

Comment: I think those are separate columns in the same row.  But OP is not clear.

Comment: Looking at last part of Q, it looks like OP is try to fill data for each category using a different logic. So they will be different rows.

Comment: Thanks Dhruv...I will try the Cross apply one and see. Since this query needs to execute everytime the report is run...so basically i will be creating a stored Proc

Answer (score 0):

Magic

```
insert into table (metricValue1, MetricValue2, MetricValue3)
select (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Med_process), 
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Hrov_contracts where flag <> N),
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM all_users where orderid = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you need an update statement, not an insert statement.

Something like this:

```
UPDATE Table
SET MetricValue = 
CASE 
    WHEN category = 'cat1' AND Name = 'Nam1' THEN
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Med_process)
    WHEN category = 'cat1' AND Name = 'Nam2' THEN
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Hrov_contracts where flag <> N)
    WHEN category = 'cat1' AND Name = 'Nam3' THEN
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM all_users where orderid = 1)
    -- same for every category and name combination
END
```